# Where do I enter my Visual Studio Team Services username and access token in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: azure-devops, github-desktop

A colleague has been having problems logging in to our Git repository hosted in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) using GitHub Desktop on the Mac. He use to have access but now cannot fetch, push, etc. Yesterday my VSTS token failed and GitHub Desktop presented me with a login window where I entered a new personal access token that I generated on our project's VSTS portal. So today I thought I'd show him how to do that. I started by revoking my personal access token in the VSTS portal. Now I cannot get access nor can I see where to enter new credentials!

When I click 'sync' in GitHub Desktop here's what I see:

> **Authentication Failed**
>
> You may not have permission to access VisualCollectionsIOS. Check 
>   Preferences to make sure you’re still logged in.

[image: error message screenshot]

But the preferences have nowhere to add my VSTS username and access token.

Where in GitHub Desktop can I enter my username and access token for my Git repository hosted in a team project in VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the credentials from OSX Keychain. Check the steps in this link for reference: [Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/). Instead of searching for the `github.com` password, as the reference suggests, search for the `visualstudio.com` password. When the `visualstudio.com` password entries are deleted GitHub Desktop will prompt you for your username and personal access token again.